# Are $S_3 \times \Bbb Z_4$ and $S_4$ isomorphic groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to prove $S_3 \times \Bbb{Z}_4$ and $S_4 $ are not  isomorphic groups ?

Comment: Please write it like this: $S_3 \times \mathbf{Z}_4$ and $S_4$, in both the question and the title.

Comment: Thank you, but in title I can't change.

Comment: Another route: the only cyclic order four subgroups of $S_4$ are generated by $4$-cycles, and none of them are normal like $\Bbb Z_4$ is within $S_3\times \Bbb Z_4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another hint:

$S_4$ has $9$ elements of order $2$ whereas $S_3 \times \Bbb Z_4$ has $7$ elements of order $2$

Comment: Or, for people who are too  lazy to count that high, $S_3\times\mathbb Z_4$ has only two elements of order $3$, whereas $S_4$ has more than two (in fact eight, but counting up to $3$ suffices to prove non-isomorphism).

Answer (score 4):

Hint: There a bunch of ways to do this, but one such way is to notice that $S_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ has a cyclic subgroup of order $12$ and $S_4$ does not.

Answer (score 1):

The symmetric group $S_4$ has trivial center, i.e., $Z(S_4)=1$, whereas
$$
Z(S_3\times C_4)=Z(S_3)\times Z(C_4)\cong 1\times C_4\cong C_4.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Find an isometry-invariant property that differs between them.

Comment: S4 does not contain any element of order 24 but S3×Z4 does.

Comment: @ThirumalPachaiyappan Then that proves they're not isomorphic. If there were an isometry between them, it would send the order-24 element to an order-24 element. Although I believe it's order-12m not 24.

Comment: @ThirumalPachaiyappan Actually, neither group has an element of order 24, since they are non-abelian and so cannot be cyclic. Both groups have order 24.

Comment: Yes it has an element of order 12 not 24. Thank you.

Comment: "Isometry" (same metric) is not the usual term here; isomorphism is more usual.